# Learning how to access data from an API using Guzzle

Tags: php, api, laravel, laravel-5.1, guzzle

I'm building a new application that requires the use of an API, in particular one that uses OAuth, but to begin with I'm trying to just use a simple API to wrap my head around how to use one in an application as I've never used an API before.

I'm running a fresh Laravel 5.1 project on my localhost with the `Guzzle` library installed.

Following the instructions from the [Guzzle documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/), I believe I have set this up right, but I can't make heads or tales of the response I am getting.

The API I am trying to use is http://freegeoip.net/ and the format for making a request is `freegeoip.net/{format}/{IP_or_hostname}`.

I've set up a page where I can type in an IP address and submit this, to which it is then run by the following function in my controller:

```
public function retrieve(Request $request)
    {
        $url = "http://freegeoip.net/json/" . $request->ipaddress;
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->request('GET', $url);
        dd($response);
    }
```

My routes and everything are set up correctly, and I am referencing Guzzle at the top of my controller with:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

But the response I get from `dd($response);` doesn't make any sense to me or give any hints as to how I could get any information from it.

**This is what the `dd($response)` outputs**

```
Response {#195 ▼
  -reasonPhrase: "OK"
  -statusCode: 200
  -headers: array:8 [▶]
  -headerLines: array:8 [▶]
  -protocol: "1.1"
  -stream: Stream {#186 ▶}
}
```

**But when I run the equivalent URL through my browser I get**

```
{"ip":"202.21.xxx.xxx","country_code":"NZ","country_name":"New Zealand","region_code":"WGN","region_name":"Wellington","city":"Wellington","zip_code":"6011","time_zone":"Pacific/Auckland","latitude":-41.283,"longitude":174.784,"metro_code":0}
```

Can anyone help out with what I'm doing wrong or point to some good resources on how to get started using APIs with Laravel. There's a lot on how to build a Laravel API but not how to access one from Laravel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well after a huge amount of digging, it turns out I was simply missing `json_decode()`.

The request works fine when I run it like:

```
public function retrieve(Request $request)
    {
        $url = "http://freegeoip.net/json/" . $request->ipaddress;
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->request('GET', $url);
        dd(json_decode($response->getBody()));
    }
```

Answering this for anyone else who has trouble like this in the future :).